# Can't get notifications to work in Bosun

Tags: monitoring, bosun

Looking for help with configuring Bosun.

I can't get notifications to work. I have configured hipchat, pagerduty and (added later) print notification types, and neither works. To make things work, the hipchat one worked once or twice and I have no idea why.

The alerts are displayed on dashboard with proper subject, and also if I test the alert in Rule Editor, everything looks good, with template subject and body being OK and so on.

My config is this:

```
template hipchat {
    subject = {{.Last.Status}}: {{.Alert.Name}} on {{.Group | len}}   items
    body = {"color":"red","message":"{{.Alert.Name}} is {{.Last.Status}}","notify":false,"message_format":"text"}
}

template pagerduty {
  subject = "subject foo123"
}

notification print {
        print = true
}

notification hipchat {
    next = print
    post = https://foo.hipchat.com/v2/room/123/notification?auth_token=the_token
    body = {"color":"red","message":"foo123 {{.Alert.Name}} is {{.Last.Status}}","notify":false,"message_format":"text"}
    contentType = application/json
}

notification pagerduty {
   post = https://events.pagerduty.com/generic/2010-04-15/create_event.json
   contentType = application/json
   body = {"service_key": "the_key", "event_type": "trigger", "description": "foo123"}
   next = print
}

alert foo.bar.error {
    template = pagerduty
    $notes = "This is bad."
    $data = lscount("logstash", "foo", "bar:baz", "1s", "10m", "1m")
    $total = sum($data)
    warn = $total > 0
    crit = $total > 5
    warnNotification = hipchat
    critNotification = pagerduty
    #unknownIsNormal = true # this doesn't work too
}
```

Comment: 1) Which Bosun version are you using? Many fixes were made since 0.4.x.
2) Does `print` notification shows up in Bosun log?
3) I usually test http notification via http://requestb.in/ to see if everything comes right.
4) Another one, Bosun notifies only one time when an alert becomes non-normal. You have to make it transition to non-normal state again. Or use `log = true`.

Comment: Thank you for valuable questions asked.   
1. I run Bosun using the official docker image  
    `/bosun/bosun --version
    bosun version 0.5.0-alpha-dev (191a2410063a4ba1163ae922d86550fc3e58f36f) built 2015-11-11T16:14:12Z`  
2. print notifications do not show up in stdout which I understand is where they would appear in case running it in docker container  
3. I use ngrep to see nothing comes out  
4. That may be the clue. It goes to unknown (0 entries in ES) then to   normal, or back to critical. The option to treat unknown as normal is not recognized, dunno why.

Comment: You can run new container every time to test it, or even put `next = same_notification_name` and `timeout = 5s` in notification definition. `unknownIsNormal` is new, added on Feb24 this year.

Comment: @PawełRein, I have a very similar problem, only with mail. Turns out only first notification for an alert name is being sent. If I rename the alert, it sends email correctly, but only first time. I'm also using logstash. Did you figure it out finally?

Comment: @elkarel thanks for your comment. I gave up, as I was running out of time for R&D and I switched to using Elastalert which has different disadvantages, but does the job for me. I'll have a look at Bosun again, some day, for sure.

Comment: Turns out you have to close the alert in order to keep receiving it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298395/bosun-only-first-notification-being-sent