# Bosun: only first notification being sent

Tags: bosun

I am experiencing strange behaviour with my first-time Bosun config. 
It seems I'm receiving mail only first time the alert is being called.
I am surely misunderstanding something.. Here's my .conf file:

```
smtpHost = ${env.BOSUN_MAIL_SERV}
smtpUsername =  ${env.BOSUN_MAIL_USER}
smtpPassword = ${env.BOSUN_MAIL_PASS}
emailFrom = ${env.BOSUN_MAIL_FROM}
httpListen = :8070
timeAndDate = 31
stateFile = ../bosun.state
ledisDir = ../ledis_data
checkFrequency = 10s
logstashElasticHosts = ${env.BOSUN_ES_HOSTS}

notification onError {
    email = elkarel@company.net
    print = true
}

template generic {
    subject = Test alert
    body = `<p>Alert: {{.Alert.Name}} triggered </p>`
}

alert company.errors.rate.exceeds0 {
    template = generic
    unknownIsNormal = true
    runEvery = 1
    $notes = "The rate of errors exceeds 1."
    crit = 1
    critNotification = onError
}
```

As you can see, `crit` is set always. However, nothing never happens. The Bosun output is like this:

```
elkarel@thinkPad-E550:~/Bosun$ ./bosun-linux-amd64-0.5.0-rc3 -c company.conf 
2016/05/18 13:14:45 enabling syslog
2016/05/18 13:14:45 info: search.go:194: Loading last datapoints from redis
2016/05/18 13:14:45 info: search.go:201: Done
2016/05/18 13:14:45 info: bolt.go:53: RestoreState
2016/05/18 13:14:45 info: bolt.go:65: RestoreState done in 23.954µs
2016/05/18 13:14:45 info: check.go:513: check alert company.errors.rate.exceeds0 start
2016/05/18 13:14:45 info: check.go:537: check alert company.errors.rate.exceeds0 done (463.184µs): 1 crits, 0 warns, 0 unevaluated, 0 unknown
2016/05/18 13:14:45 info: web.go:154: bosun web listening on: :8070
2016/05/18 13:14:45 info: web.go:155: tsdb host: 
2016/05/18 13:14:45 info: alertRunner.go:55: runHistory on company.errors.rate.exceeds0 took 11.525239ms
2016/05/18 13:14:55 info: check.go:513: check alert company.errors.rate.exceeds0 start
2016/05/18 13:14:55 info: check.go:537: check alert company.errors.rate.exceeds0 done (418.716µs): 1 crits, 0 warns, 0 unevaluated, 0 unknown
2016/05/18 13:14:55 info: alertRunner.go:55: runHistory on company.errors.rate.exceeds0 took 2.298315ms

2016/05/18 13:15:05 info: notify.go:147: Batching and sending unknown notifications
2016/05/18 13:15:05 info: notify.go:177: Done sending unknown notifications
2016/05/18 13:15:05 info: check.go:513: check alert company.errors.rate.exceeds0 start
2016/05/18 13:15:05 info: check.go:537: check alert company.errors.rate.exceeds0 done (380.23µs): 1 crits, 0 warns, 0 unevaluated, 0 unknown
2016/05/18 13:15:05 info: alertRunner.go:55: runHistory on company.errors.rate.exceeds0 took 919.933µs
2016/05/18 13:15:15 info: check.go:513: check alert company.errors.rate.exceeds0 start
2016/05/18 13:15:15 info: check.go:537: check alert company.errors.rate.exceeds0 done (351.148µs): 1 crits, 0 warns, 0 unevaluated, 0 unknown
2016/05/18 13:15:15 info: alertRunner.go:55: runHistory on company.errors.rate.exceeds0 took 807.104µs
2016/05/18 13:15:25 info: notify.go:147: Batching and sending unknown notifications
2016/05/18 13:15:25 info: notify.go:177: Done sending unknown notifications
2016/05/18 13:15:25 info: check.go:513: check alert company.errors.rate.exceeds0 start
2016/05/18 13:15:25 info: check.go:537: check alert company.errors.rate.exceeds0 done (439.26µs): 1 crits, 0 warns, 0 unevaluated, 0 unknown
2016/05/18 13:15:25 info: alertRunner.go:55: runHistory on company.errors.rate.exceeds0 took 2.429369ms
```

So he knows the alert resulted in a critical state, but does not send any notification. 
However, if I change alert name to `company.errors.rate.exceeds0_newname`, the notification is fired and mail arrives:

```
elkarel@thinkPad-E550:~/Bosun$ ./bosun-linux-amd64-0.5.0-rc3 -c company.conf 
2016/05/18 13:18:35 enabling syslog
2016/05/18 13:18:35 info: search.go:194: Loading last datapoints from redis
2016/05/18 13:18:35 info: search.go:201: Done
2016/05/18 13:18:35 info: bolt.go:53: RestoreState
2016/05/18 13:18:35 info: bolt.go:65: RestoreState done in 28.431µs
2016/05/18 13:18:35 info: check.go:513: check alert company.errors.rate.exceeds_newname start
2016/05/18 13:18:35 info: check.go:537: check alert company.errors.rate.exceeds_newname done (638.843µs): 1 crits, 0 warns, 0 unevaluated, 0 unknown
2016/05/18 13:18:35 info: web.go:154: bosun web listening on: :8070
2016/05/18 13:18:35 info: web.go:155: tsdb host: 
2016/05/18 13:18:35 info: alertRunner.go:55: runHistory on company.errors.rate.exceeds_newname took 2.380886ms
2016/05/18 13:18:35 info: notify.go:57: Test alert
2016/05/18 13:18:36 info: notify.go:115: relayed alert company.errors.rate.exceeds_newname{} to [elkarel@company.net] sucessfully. Subject: 10 bytes. Body: 99 bytes.
2016/05/18 13:18:45 info: check.go:513: check alert company.errors.rate.exceeds_newname start
2016/05/18 13:18:45 info: check.go:537: check alert company.errors.rate.exceeds_newname done (558.396µs): 1 crits, 0 warns, 0 unevaluated, 0 unknown
2016/05/18 13:18:45 info: alertRunner.go:55: runHistory on company.errors.rate.exceeds_newname took 746.837µs
2016/05/18 13:18:55 info: notify.go:147: Batching and sending unknown notifications
2016/05/18 13:18:55 info: notify.go:177: Done sending unknown notifications
2016/05/18 13:18:55 info: check.go:513: check alert company.errors.rate.exceeds_newname start
2016/05/18 13:18:55 info: check.go:537: check alert company.errors.rate.exceeds_newname done (394.645µs): 1 crits, 0 warns, 0 unevaluated, 0 unknown
2016/05/18 13:18:55 info: alertRunner.go:55: runHistory on company.errors.rate.exceeds_newname took 956.957µs
2016/05/18 13:19:05 info: check.go:513: check alert company.errors.rate.exceeds_newname start
2016/05/18 13:19:05 info: check.go:537: check alert company.errors.rate.exceeds_newname done (404.464µs): 1 crits, 0 warns, 0 unevaluated, 0 unknown
2016/05/18 13:19:05 info: alertRunner.go:55: runHistory on company.errors.rate.exceeds_newname took 832.393µs
2016/05/18 13:19:15 info: notify.go:147: Batching and sending unknown notifications
```

Notifications are being sent apparently only with "new" alerts. Is this  how Bosun works? Do I have to resend the notification until somebody acks it?

The mail server is gmail.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Bosun only sends notification when an alert transitions from normal to warn or from warn to crit. You can, however chain notifications or even specify

```
notification onError {
    email = elkarel@company.net
    print = true
    timeout = 1m
    next = onError
}
```

That way Bosun will send notification every minute until the alert gets acknowledged.

Comment: Hi elementai, thanks for your answer! I knew about the next and is working for me. But when I change crit = 0, and after say 1 hour I set it back to 1, no new alert arrives. Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: OK after some PM with elementai, turns out that the first notification has to be closed, if you wish to receive another notification of that alert. So always close those alerts boys!

Comment: Also get a notification if it goes from normal-> unknown,warn->unknown,crit->unknown. So it notifies when the greatest severity in the lifetime of incident increases.

Comment: But there is a problem that my alert has gone to normal, the chained notification does not stop(until human ack or close it). Is there any option to close it automaticly when my alert goes normal?